# Can't create availability group , big error message

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, clustering

hello I am setting up my "high availability group" and I have a little problem, I have this error message . [image]

maybe I have to validate my cluster first? I already tried to validate but I also receive an error message like this

[image]

WHAT SHOULD I DO?  thanks.

Comment: yes of course it was enabled , here is the version Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) @McNets

Comment: what does the error logs says ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

In PowerShell, run the following:

```
Get-ClusterResourceType | where name -like "SQL Server Availability Group"
```

Is any result brought back? If not do the following in PowerShell:

```
Add-ClusterResourceType -Name "SQL Server Availability Group" -DisplayName "SQL Server Availability Group" -Dll "C:\Windows\System32\hadrres.dll"
```